# Looking for late 90s shareware open world racing game

Tags: identify-this-game

I'm trying to track down a shareware racing game released somewhere between 1999 and 2004 -  or at least, my parents found it bundled in a computer magazine during that time.

Here's what I remember about it:

- It was a Win9x game, 3D Flat shaded with hard edges and basically no textures, no actual transparency and rather sparse geometry; It wasn't due to low settings, it was just stylized like that;
- It was open world;
- The scope of the game was basically collecting (pinkish?) waypoints randomly placed around the map within a time limit;
- It was probably made by an European dev;
- the "buy the game" screen showed a few other maps, including a "rainbows in the sky" fantasy setting.

It seems that most websites curating shareware games have just disappeared from the face of the earth, so I haven't found any reference about it online.

Does my description ring any bells to anyone?

Comment: Interstate 76 or Interstate 82 ?

Comment: Nope, it was clearly a small team or one-man made game. Much more lo-fi than the Interstate games.

Comment: Can you remember which magazine it might have been ?

Comment: An italian magazine by Future Media called "Giochi per il mio computer" which was the local edition of "PC Gamer". I've already tried browsing archive.org for some clues but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Since I see there's one close vote, I won't wait to mention that, if you don't get an answer here, try /r/TipOfMyJoystick or the #identify-a-game channel on the MobyGames Discord.

Comment: I wish I could give some more details but there's very little to add. I mean, I thought it was popular enough given it was deemed worthy of being bundled on a magazine. I'll check it out on discord.

Comment: Do you remember anything about the cars? Were they street cars? F1-type? Off-road vehicles? Were you alone against time, or were there NPCs?

Comment: @thkala you were absolutely alone against time, and the car in the demo was just one extremely low poly sedan. The physics and handling weren’t too arcades, but very far from current day realism level.

Comment: Are you really sure that it is a Win9x game? Low Poly graphics without texturing could also mean, that it was a DOS game.